# how to ignore a line in `dart-lang/coverage`

Tags: flutter, dart, code-coverage, test-coverage, codecov

#### use case

[codecov](http://codecov.io) sees `super` as in need for test,

[image]

not sure being sure if writing a test for this ***keyword***

- would be meaningful
- how to write such a test

I'd like to exclude the line from [coverage](https://pub.dev/packages/coverage) until my doubts are cleared

#### question

how do I ignore a line in `dart-lang/coverage`

Comment: Make 2 tests 1 for begin null (expect begin  is null) and 1 for end null (expect end is null)

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/coverage/issues/162

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I see this. Not perfect, but a solution

```dart
// coverage:ignore-line to ignore one line.
// coverage:ignore-start and // coverage:ignore-end to ignore range of lines inclusive.
// coverage:ignore-file to ignore the whole file.
```

Answer (score 2):

This might help meanwhile:

```
// coverage:ignore-start
}) : super(
begin: begin,
end: end,
);
// coverage:ignore-end
```

Answer (score 1):

In documentation for `widget_tester.dart`

```dart
testWidgets('MyWidget asserts invalid bounds', (WidgetTester tester) async {
  await tester.pumpWidget(MyWidget(-1));
  expect(tester.takeException(), isAssertionError); // or isNull, as appropriate.
});
```

Comment: thanks, but what about super? [editing the question]
also... it's not a widget